# Linkedin API: 404 Account not found

Tags: java, rest, http-status-code-404, linkedin-api

I'm trying to find conversions rules by Ad Account using https://api.linkedin.com/rest/conversions API endpoint. However, some accounts are returning an error message "Account not found" with a status code 404.

I tried both POST and GET requests using Offline Conversions (Legacy API) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/offline-conversions?view=li-lms-2023-05&tabs=http#find-offline-conversion-dmp-segments-by-ad-account

Updated the ticket with a sample code.

curl -X GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/conversions?q=account&account=urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A{sponsoredAccountId}' 
-H 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {INSERT_TOKEN}' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H 'LinkedIn-Version: 202311'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated the ticket with a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your link and I get this error: "A version must be present. Please specify a version by adding the LinkedIn-Version header". I hope it helps.

Comment: I did add a LinkedIn-Version header.